# MySql error, trying to use INNER JOIN to select data from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm getting this error, when i try to select data from two tables in my database.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN hbr_galleri
>       ON hbr_billede.GalleriID = hbr_galleri.GalleriID
>       LIMIT ' at line 4

This is the query:

(Sorry for the danish table/column names)

```
SELECT 
    `hbr_billede.BilledeID`, 
    `hbr_billede.GalleriID`, 
    `hbr_billede.FilePath`, 
    `hbr_billede.FilePathThumb`, 
    `hbr_billede.UploadetDato`, 
    `hbr_billede.UploadetAf`, 
    `hbr_billede.Fotograf`, 
    `hbr_billede.Caption`, 
    `hbr_billede.FeaturedFrontGallery`, 
    `hbr_billede.FeaturedWorldtour`, 
    `hbr_galleri.GalleriNavn`
FROM `hbr_billede` 
INNER JOIN `hbr_galleri`
ON `hbr_billede.GalleriID` = `hbr_galleri.GalleriID`
WHERE `hbr_billede.BilledeID` = 17
```

I have tried multiple ways to make it work in phpMyAdmin, but with no luck. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong, or point me in the direction?

My sql create scripts for these two tables, looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE hbr_galleri
(
    GalleriID int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    GalleriNavn varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    OprettetDato timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    DatoEvent date NOT NULL,
    AntalBilleder int,
    FeaturedBillede int,
    OprettetAf int NOT NULL, /* BrugerID*/
    Offentligt boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
    unikt_galleri varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (GalleriID),
    UNIQUE KEY unikt_galleri (GalleriNavn,DatoEvent),
    FOREIGN KEY (OprettetAf) REFERENCES hbr_bruger(BrugerID) /*ON DELETE CASCADE*/
);

CREATE TABLE hbr_billede
(
    BilledeID int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    GalleriID int NOT NULL,
    FilePath varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FilePathThumb varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    UploadetDato timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UploadetAf int NOT NULL,
    Fotograf varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    Caption varchar(255),
    FeaturedFrontGallery boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    FeaturedWorldtour boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    PRIMARY KEY (BilledeID),
    FOREIGN KEY (GalleriID) REFERENCES hbr_galleri(GalleriID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE (FilePath),
    UNIQUE (FilePathThumb)
);
```

Comment: you query is incorrect... join clauses happen before where clauses

Comment: Oh god, that was a stupid mistake. But that helped, not im at least getting another error.
#1054 - Unknown column 'hbr_billede.BilledeID' in 'field list' 
I don't get why it says its unknown, cause it exists, and its in the select part of the query...

Comment: column descriptors should separate table and column if you're using backicks. e.g. \`hbr_billede\`.\`BilledeID\`

Comment: Thnx alot. that did the trick. Away with the stupid backticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `INNER JOIN` clause before `WHERE`. You also need to fix the backticks, for example this

```
`hbr_billede.BilledeID`
```

should be changed to this

```
`hbr_billede`.`BilledeID`
```

Try to change your query to this

```
SELECT 
    `hbr_billede`.`BilledeID`, 
    `hbr_billede`.`GalleriID`, 
    `hbr_billede`.`FilePath`, 
    `hbr_billede`.`FilePathThumb`, 
    `hbr_billede`.`UploadetDato`, 
    `hbr_billede`.`UploadetAf`, 
    `hbr_billede`.`Fotograf`, 
    `hbr_billede`.`Caption`, 
    `hbr_billede`.`FeaturedFrontGallery`, 
    `hbr_billede`.`FeaturedWorldtour`, 
    `hbr_galleri`.`GalleriNavn`
FROM `hbr_billede` 
INNER JOIN `hbr_galleri`
ON `hbr_billede`.`GalleriID` = `hbr_galleri`.`GalleriID`
WHERE `BilledeID` = 17
```

Comment: Yes, those two things did the trick.
Whats the point in using the backticks anyway? phpMyAdmin adds them by default if you use their interface to build a query, so there must be some reasoning behind doing it.

Comment: select user from table won't work. select \`user\` from \`table\` will. It's for differenciation reserved names from column names

Comment: Ahh, that makes perfect sense :)

Comment: For more information regarding MySQL reserved words, see this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html